# using javascript or jquery how to custom expand a tree branch when build tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tree

I want to build a tree using bootstrap like the one in the link http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/

I've manage to close all tree branches by adding the following line in script

```
$('.tree li').hide();
$('.tree li:second').show();
```

but this isn't what i want.

I want to close some branches of the tree and open others:

here is the script i use:

```
 <script>
   $(function () {
   $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
   $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
    var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) {
        children.hide('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
    } else {
        children.show('fast');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
</script>
```

-i have some ideas how to make this work, but i have no idea how to implement it
    my idea is to ad an attribut to a

tag in html and in javascript to read that attribute and all of its children to hide

P.S also i would appreciate if you have an idea how to close a hole level of children not just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and try-error methods , i've manage to find a solution for closing at a custom level of children

here is the solution for lvl 3 children

```
$('.tree li>ul>li>ul').hide();
$('.tree li:first').show();
```